# 403 Exception on Fetching Firebase ML Model in Production

Tags: firebase, google-mlkit, firebase-machine-learning

Getting a strange 403 exception when trying to fetch our Firebase ML model in production. Not sure why, in our debug build it works just fine (it's a separate firebase project), but pretty much identical to production in terms of setup. There shouldn't be any issues on the authentication front, and our models are definitely uploaded to Firebase ML as custom models, and the google-services.json file is up to date. Any leads on what this may be? Very confused why this is happening

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: uk.c: Permission error while fetching model (insufficient-photo): HTTP response from Firebase Download Service: [403 - Forbidden: Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.]
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:6)
                                                                                                    at a60.b9.h(PhotoUploader.kt:11)
                                                                                                    at a60.b9.c(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                    at a60.a9.onComplete(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:22)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7918)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Checked the Firebase access permissions, and it looks like Firebase ML should be accessible.

Comment: "Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked" This implies that your production build is not properly identifying itself to the server. You'll need to start looking at documentation regarding registering client apps with your backend, probably specifically relating to Google Play Services based on the stack trace.